# DDD: References to other layers from domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a backend for an app that sends push notifications to various users under certain conditions.
So far there is an aggregate root `PushNotification` and an interface `PushNotificationSender`, whose concrete implementation is defined via dependency injection.

The `PushNotificationSender` belongs to the `Infrastructure Layer` or?
I also think that the decision when and to whom to send a push notification should be in the `Domain Layer`.

But how do I send a push notification? As I understood it, the domain layer should not have any dependency on the infrastructure layer. Without this dependency I can't call the `PushNotificationSender` and therefore I can't send a push notification.
How could this be solved?

There is also a feature request that a `PushNotification` can be sent on a certain date. This additionally brings the `Infrastructure Layer` into play, because I have to store this `ScheduledPushNotification` in the database with a Due date until the Due date is reached.
My current approach is an `Application Layer Service` with a method `schedulePushNotificationForDate(pushNotification, date)`, in which `ScheduledPushNotificationRepository` is injected by DI.
Now I have again the problem that the decision which push notification should be sent when to which user is a business rule and should be accordingly in the `Domain Layer`.
But this rule should not access the application layer. How could this case be solved?

### Edit - A bit more context

The system is kind of a fitness training app with a frontend on mobile devices and one monolithic backend.

There are the following two use cases:

1. After a user finishes a workout, all users that follow him should receive a push notification
2. A user can set a reminder for a workout. This reminder will send a push notification.

As discussed in some comments here, I'm not convinced that sending these push notifications should be only the responsibility of something in the infrastructure layer. I understand that normally it should be like this, but in this case the requirement clearly states that a push notification should be send. So in my opinion this is a business requirement and therefore belongs in the domain layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also think that the decision when and to whom to send a push notification should be in the Domain Layer.

You are right about that. Additionally, sending notification usually happens *asynchronously* in a separate transaction. You may consider publishing a *domain event* asynchronously with the notification details (e.g. whom the notification is intended to) the notification sender needs. A *domain service* can listen to those notification domain events and call the `PushNotificationSender` (which you rightly pointed out is an infrastructure layer concern) with parameters extracted from the domain event. Having notification in a separate transaction has an additional benefit of imposing *retry operations* whose success is unceration and would block the main business transaction unnecessarily.

> There is also a feature request that a PushNotification can be sent on a certain date.

If I got you right, you mean sending some notifications on a certain date instead of immediately. In that case, the domain service can do the persisting with scheduled date for you instead of your current application service. Moreover, the domain service may put the notification date if it is uniform over all users or the domain event may carry the date with it if it varies from user to user.

Comment: Good idea to use domain events for this! The only thing I don't like about it, is that it goes a bit against the definition from Evans in DDD Reference: "A domain event is a full-fledged part of the domain model, a representation of something that happened in the domain. "
In my case, it wouldn't be something that happened in the domain, or?
Because I would use an event like _SendPushNotification_ which isn't really something that happened.

Comment: I meant domain event exactly in Evans' sense, expressed in its _ubiquitous language_ (e.g. _order placed_, _user confirmed_, etc.) You are sending push notification because something had happened in your domain. I meant that _what happened_ to be the domain event.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. I'm currently reading the chapter about domain events in "Implementing DDD" and there is a pretty similar example with sending an email as reaction to an event. But this is done in an application service. But should it be the concern of an application service to decide which PushNotification should be sent in response to a specific event. In my view this seams like a business rule and so should be in the domain model. Do you understand what I means?

Comment: _Implementing DDD (V. Vernon, 2013)_ also clarifies (p. 302) that domain services can also be domain event subscribers. The deciding factor is 'domain-specific reasons'. If the subscriber doesn't involve any business rules, then you may go with an application service or if the subscriber's logic involves business rules, then go with a domain service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on this, but I disagree with the currently accepted answer.

Unless the purpose of your application is to monitor or provide push notification services, it does not belong to the domain layer but to the infrastructure layer: push notifications are used for communication between your system and an *external actor*. Also one could imagine that, in a subsequent version, you'll want to switch from push notifications to SMS, and even have your user choose the notification strategy, **without changing your application business logic**.

What goes in the domain layer is usually what you want to notify users about. For instance, if your application is about e-commerce and you have some delays with the banking system, you might want to allow the user to navigate away from the checkout page, and send an asynchronous push notification to the user when the banking system confirms reception of the payment.

In this situation, the domain layer is about the reception of payments. An adapter receives the information from the banking API, then kicks the domain layer which would ensure the payment was not aborted. The domain would then raise a `PaymentReceived` domain event, which can be handled by the infrastructure layer. Especially the `IPaymentNotification` infrastructure port, implemented in the `PushNotificationAdapter`, would handle the event, sending a push notification to the user when the payment occurs.

[image: UML diagram]

If you need to schedule some notifications, you can entirely bypass the domain layer. The domain layer's purpose is to validate that state changing operations do not violate any business constraint. Sending notifications is not a state changing operation, so you can simply implement everything in the infrastructure layer. You can implement an adapter with a timer, which will execute code periodically. This adapter can reference another adapter, either directly if you can afford tight coupling, or through an interface (port) if you need low coupling.

Comment: Shouldn't the domain layer model the business processes and their requirements? And in my case the business requirement is to send a specific notification to a specific group of users in response to some event. And therefore I don't agree with you that the infrastructure layer should do this.

Comment: Also another argument: A huge benefit in my opinion of DDD is good readability of the code.  But if I move business requirements out of the domain layer this readability is diminished because I always have to mentally map what else happens in this place.

Comment: *Send a specific notification to a specific group of users in response to some event* is not a **business** requirement. A business requirement is what determines if an event can occur or not. I could give better examples if you disclose what the event is in your case.

Comment: Also moving a business requirement out of the domain layer is not simply diminishing the readability, it is a violation of the first DDD principle. My point here is that notifications are by design infrastructure concerns and not business code.

Comment: I'll expand on the original question later, maybe you'll get some better context.

Comment: But I don't get what you mean with that it isn't a business requirement. If the stakeholder says: "If a user does this, send him a push notification" isn't this clearly a business requirement? And if not, what kind of requirement is it than?

Comment: Because it is a customer requirement does not mean it is a business requirement. A business requirement is something universal, that all applications in that industry must implement. Example: you cannot use a lifting > 100kg without a spotter ; here your customer wants *this* application to send a notification, so this is an *application* requirement.

Comment: In your context, your domain will model `Workout` and raise a `WorkoutCompleted` business event. When that event triggers, your infrastructure layer will handle the event by sending a push notification to the user.

Comment: Domain model is about the purpose of the application. The purpose of your application is fitness and workouts. You want to track the state of workouts, hence the fact that you send notifications about workout state (workout complete / workout incomplete). Notifications would be in the domain model if your *users* (not customer) were interested in the notifications state (notification sent / notification failed to send)